# How to include multi-line html from django template into javascript variable

Tags: django, django-templates, addslashes

From a Django template, I would like to include an html snippet from a file, say `mysnippet.html`:

```
<div>
    blah
</div>
```

into a javascript variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var myvar = {% include 'mysnippet.html' %}
</script>
```

The problem is that the new lines would need to be escaped. Otherwise, Javascript complains for "unterminated string literal".

I know slashes can be added with `{{x|addslashes}}` but I don't know how to do it for the `{% include %}` tag.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

have you tried [`filter`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#filter) template tag?

```
{% filter addslashes %}{% include 'mysnippet.html' %}{% endfilter %}
```

better escape of all special characters is to use `escapejs` filter:

```
{% filter escapejs %}{% include 'mysnippet.html' %}{% endfilter %}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. I wrote in a separate answer how I fixed it eventually.

Comment: @gozzilli and `escapejs` built-in filter wasn't working for you? http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs

Comment: Ouch! Yes, it does work, sorry I should have RTFM. :( The only difference is that is looks a bit horrible on the HTML source, as it is printed all on one line, but still you're right, escapejs is just what I needed...

Comment: @Jerzyk can you add escapejs in the main body of the answer, maybe on a new line? That's the real answer to the question.

Comment: btw. remove your own answers :D

Answer (score 2):

Following Jerzyk suggestion (thanks!), I've used

```
{% filter addslashes %}{% include 'mysnippet.html' %}{% endfilter %}
```

Unfortunately I realised that it doesn't escape new lines as I thought, but quotes. So I defined a new filter:

```
def escapenewline(value):
    """
    Adds a slash before any newline. Useful for loading a multi-line html chunk
    into a Javascript variable.
    """
    return value.replace('\n', '\\\n')
escapenewline.is_safe = True
escapenewline = stringfilter(escapenewline)

register.filter('escapenewline', escapenewline)
```

And used it instead of addslashes:

```
{% filter escapenewline %}{% include 'mysnippet.html' %}{% endfilter %}
```

On the Django docs there is a how-to on [custom templates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you are using javascript. If you don't mind using jQuery and some AJAX along with it, there is an alternate way to assign html to a javascript variable.

Create a view to display your snippet:

```
# views.py
def mysnippet(request):
    return render(
        request,
        'yourapp/mysnippet.html',
    )

# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('yourapp.views',
    url(r'mysnippet/$', 'mysnippet', name='mysnippet'),
)
```

You can place the following in your template or separate the javascript in its own file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("/yourapp/mysnippet/", function(data) {
        var myvar = data;
    });
});
</script>
```

`myvar` should now contain the html, the new lines don't need to be escaped in that case.